# API testing with TestContainers in Corda

Tags: corda, testcontainers

I'm coding a REST API that connects to my Corda Node via Corda RPC. I'm trying to create a mock testing corda network with TestContainers so that I can verify the behaviors of my REST API. I know Corda has official docker image. Is there any guidance on how might I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at this/divide this into two parts.

1. Server side testing - Testing your node RPC endpoints.
2. Client side testing - Testing your rest endpoints.

For the first part, you can use the NodeDriver to write the integration tests. Using the NodeDriver, you can bring up nodes locally to run flows and inspect state updates. The NodeDriver allows you to access the node using RPC endpoints. You can read more about NodeDriver [here](https://medium.com/corda/integration-testing-of-cordapps-using-nodedriver-66ee1ebe8b24).

For the second part, you can use something like mockito to mock the RPC calls and test your client logic.

This way you will easily be able to test client and server side.

To do an actual end to end integration test, you will have to start the docker nodes using a script and then you can test the methods from the client code.